# NameError: name 'key_account_id' is not defined How to fix this Error?

Tags: python-3.x

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 cs[key_account_id]

NameError: name 'key_account_id' is not defined

cs[key_account_id]

I was trying to access the key_account_id column. What should i do to fix this

Comment: You need quotes around it.  `cs["key_account_id"]`  Otherwise it thinks `key_account_id` is a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the name of the column in between '' for the code to run. This should fix the Error.
cs['key_account_id']